# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ide

I have searched all the links which come on the first page of the stack exchange search for this title, but none really worked.The connector is added in class path and this code works on my school computer. This is the coding of a jButton in a jFrame.

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    try {
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/game", "root", "password");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sfld = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        String op = (String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
        String crit = jTextField1.getText();
        String query;
        if (sfld.equals("contactNo")) {
            query = "select * from user where " + sfld + " " + op + " " + crit + ";";
        } else {
            query = "select * from user where " + sfld + " " + op + " \"" + crit + "\";";
        }
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        int count = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            count++;
            model.addRow(new Object[]{
                rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3),
                rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5)
            });
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        jTable1.setModel(model);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It worked sometime back, but it is giving the same message after every try. After that I reinstalled mysql a few times, and changed the OS to Linux Mint 18 KDE but still the smae error haunts me. 
I am using a Intel i3 64 bit processor(if this helps).
All help appreciated!

EDIT1:

The full stack trace

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/game
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at SearchFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(SearchFrame.java:127)
at SearchFrame.access$000(SearchFrame.java:15)
at SearchFrame$2.actionPerformed(SearchFrame.java:71)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

**EDIT2:**

This is the stack trace when I change the driver to com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at SearchFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(SearchFrame.java:126)
at SearchFrame.access$000(SearchFrame.java:15)
at SearchFrame$2.actionPerformed(SearchFrame.java:71)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Show us an SSCCE. Show the full stacktrace. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Did you include your driver to your classpath?

Comment: @m0skit0 this is a project for my school, of course it is vulnerable to SQL injections! ( I tried to explain that in school but nobody cares!). I have included the driver to my classpath ( as I mentioned it worked earlier).

Comment: `java.sql.Driver` is not your driver, it is only the interface. What version of the MySQL driver are you using, because 'recent' (as in 2006 or later), will be loaded automatically (in most contexts).

Comment: @Mark mySQL version as seen when starting mySQL _Server version: 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)_

Comment: @Roofi I was asking about the version of the driver.

Comment: @Mark , if this is not what you were asking, I have no idea where to look for the version.

Comment: You say that you have added the connector to the classpath, the default filename of the MySQL Connector/J jar contains a version number.

Comment: Okay @Mark, it is _mysql-connector-java-5.1.40_. Could you please explain me how can the version of connector solve the issue. Also I just remembered that the version of mySQL which runs this code correctly is 5.11.x and the connector used in my school is 3.1.x (x means I forgot). Anyways, I am extremely grateful for your help!

Comment: 5.1.40 is the latest, so good, if you are using something like 5.1.20(ish) or older then it might be a problem. This makes it more likely that it the driver is not actually on your runtime classpath. You will need to show how you run your application.

Comment: I couldn't completely get you, but I use Shift+F6 on netbeans (run the jFrame). Also I have configured the classpath ( i think..) by right clicking on the libraries folder in the projects window, then clicking on "Add Jar/Folder..", and then selecting the mysql connector file. Also when I switch systems ( ie between school and home) I simply click on "Resolve Project Problems.." which comes as a pop-up. Then I again manually select the connector.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I foolishly tried adding the connector by right clicking the Libraries, even after netbeans had resolved the project problems, and of course reached nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL driver is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html))

Note: your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. [Use parameters and prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of concatenating.

Comment: Actually I am not supposed to protect it against SQL injections ( because then my teacher wont understand it and I wont get marks) but still I am curious how to do it in java. I would appreciate it if you could give me a link.

Comment: Thanks @m0skit0, it helped me develop a deeper understanding in the problem.