# "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found" error with code but not with gui

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

This question has been asked many times. And I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383184/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbnam?noredirect=1#comment68095310_40383184) also. My new question came when I tried using the tutorial given on the official [netbeans site](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html) which uses an gui approach to connect to mysql.I have added the connector in my classpath and tried changing "java.sql.Driver" to "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". So the question is that how is it even possible that gui works while code doesn't?

## Code:

```
try {
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/game","root","password");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query = "select * from user;";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println(rs);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

## Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/game
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:22)
```

Comment: Because the GUI has the JDBC driver in its classpath, but your application doesn't. NetBeans is a Java app. It's not the same Java app as your Java app. Just because something works in some other app (NetBeans in this case) doesn't mean that it will magically work in your app.

Comment: How do you add the jar in your classpath? How do you run your application?

Comment: @JBNizet, I use Shift+F6 to run the code on netbeans (run the jFrame). Also I have configured the classpath by right clicking on the libraries folder in the projects window, then clicking on "Add Jar/Folder..", and then selecting the mysql connector file.

Answer (score 0):

You should load `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` instead of `java.sql.Driver`.

Comment: Both are useless, actually.

Comment: Sorry @kgeorgiy, for not including that problem. I just edited my question, but thanks anyway.

Comment: That's interesting, do you still receive `SQLException` after replacement (not the `ClassNotFoundException`)?

Comment: @kgeorgiy, no the only error encountered is ClassNotFoundException, because it never reaches the Connection line.(by the way thanks for your interest)

Comment: That simplifies debugging `mysql-connector-java-X.X.X-bin.jar` is missing in `CLASSPATH`.